# Use of Actions class in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I was going through the selenium learning and when I was exploring Handling Windows and frames topic in the text, I found this code. Is it necessary to instantiate the Actions class and why we need to do that if we have never going to use it in the code?

```
public class SwitchBetweenFrames {

   public static void main(String... args) {
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("file://C:/Frames.html");

      Actions action = new Actions(driver);

      driver.switchTo().frame(0);
      WebElement txt = driver.findElement(By.name("1"));
      txt.sendKeys("I'm Frame One");

      driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

      driver.switchTo().frame(1);
      txt = driver.findElement(By.name("2"));
      txt.sendKeys("I'm Frame Two");
   }

}
```

Comment: It is not necessary to use Actions class, you can directly identify the frame by its id/name and switch it to the desired frame you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we do not need the Action if nor required. Switching to frame or alert is different and using Action is different concept.

You can use different functions of Action class

```
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html
```

And for switch is only used to shift control of webdriver from one page to another or one frame to another

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't a necessary step to instantiate [Actions class](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html), unless there is an actual need of it. For your code, it's not needed at all. Your code will still work, if you comment that section out.
Usually, **Actions class** can be used to emulate some user gestures, like: drag and drop, click and hold, etc., that by normal standards, is a tad tricky to implement.

Comment: Ya, exactly @Subh, I had read about Actions class and Action Interface in the same pdf, but suddenly I saw this code for handling multiple frames in the class, I guess, its either a printing mistake in the book or is it there for some other purpose.. Thanks for the answer..

Comment: If this is the entire code, then this is just the case of a traditional silly printing mistake, like you said. :) Because, instantiating an Actions class without using it for anything, is just asking for an unnecessary accessing of memory, don't you think? :)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not necessary to user Action class for passing control to a window. For Frames we are just passing the control to another frame. So `SwitchTo` is used.
Action classes are commonly used for mouse hover actions, drag and drop, click and hold etc like that.
If you want to know more about action class, check the link,
[Actions class](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html)